# ASP.NET Web Forms WebApp Incredibly Slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I have a web app written in ASP.NET Web Forms which takes like 7 seconds to perform any anction.
The browser tools says that the loading time is spent to actually **send** the request, while to retrieve it is fine.

Here are a couple of screenshots

[image: Network test]

[image: Network test detail]

How could I test what's wrong other that that?
I have other applications coming from the same source code, and those works fine.

The webApp is running on a local IIS server (8.5) using a classic asp.net 4 app pool and is made in Visual Studio 2010 (althought I could test it with 2013 also)

Comment: what is your code doing when that happens? what is being sent? You've showed us the results, but not what you are doing.

Comment: What is the code like on that page?  A lot of reflection

Comment: Is it possible you have a really huge viewstate for some reason?

Comment: We need to see more code to be able to help. @Telos is probably on the right track.

Comment: Yeah forgot to post some code, anyway it makes just a few calls to an Oracle DB to load the user settings in that case. I'll update the post with the code asap, anyway we use session objects quite a lot for that application..How could I check the viewstate size ?

Comment: @Alexander What code do you need? It's a pretty big project.
Anyway I found my viewstate is pretty big, but setting it to EnableViewState="false" in the web.config does not work, neither disabling it on individual pages or controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I scanned the whole thing using [Ants Performance profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

but I found nothing.

Anyway I found the cause were a really simple query which should've returned back a single line..
The db wasn't properly indexed so it took forever to load

Removing that query solved the problem for me

Thank guys